# Nginx - encoding (normalizing) part of URI

Tags: nginx

I have nginx `location` directive which purpose is to "remove" localization prefix from the URI for the `proxy_pass` directive.

For example, to make URI http://example.com/en/lalala use proxy_pass http://example.com/lalala

```
location ~ '^/(?<locale>[\w]{2})(/(?<rest>.*))?$' {
        ...
        proxy_pass http://example/$rest;
        ...
}
```

This way the `rest` variable will be decoded when passed to proxy_pass directeve. It seems to be an expected [behavior](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).

The problem is when my URI contains encoded space `%20` passed from client

```
http://example.com/lala%20lala
```

nginx decodes URI to

```
http://example.com/lala lala
```

I can see it in my error.log.

The question is - is it possible do use encoded `rest` variable somehow as it is passed from client?
If I am doing something completely wrong, please, suggest the right way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this behaviour is expected although docs also say:

If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed when processing the changed URI:

```
location /some/path/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
}
```

Nginx engineers say the same: https://serverfault.com/questions/459369/disabling-url-decoding-in-nginx-proxy

However if you append $request_uri to proxy_pass (and strip locale beforehand it may work as [said](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,256639,256647) by Nginx engineer):

```
set $modified_uri $request_uri;

if ($modified_uri ~ "^/([\w]{2})(/.*)") {
set $modified_uri $1;
}

proxy_pass http://example$modified_uri;
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I knew about $request_uri but my current knowledge of nginx didn't allow me to properly modify the URI.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you use $request_uri then IT WILL NOT CHANGE if an internal redirect is done, such as when a rewrite is performed, or applying an error_page directive. Only $uri changes in those cases, but $uri is already decoded so it can't be used as a generic replacement for $request_uri.

Comment: I had to use "set $modified_uri $uri;" instead of "set $modified_uri $request_uri;"

Answer (score 6):

I have had some success using the following with Confluence and other Atlassian applications behind nginx where special characters such as ( ) < > [ ] were causing issues.

```
location /path {
  # [... other proxy options ...]

  # set proxy path with regex
  if ($request_uri ~* "/path(/.*)") { 
    proxy_pass http://server:port/path$1;
    break;
  }

  # fallback (probably not needed)
  proxy_pass http://server:port/path;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This ended 2 days of turture :)

Answer (score 1):

The set directive can do the trick. It keeps the encoding intact or rather encodes decoded string.

```
location ~ '^/(?<locale>[\w]{2})(/(?<rest>.*))?$' {
        ...
        set $encoded_rest $rest
        proxy_pass http://example/$encoded_rest;
        ...
}
```

Comment: `set` does not url-encode the value.